# How to embed interop.dll x86 and x64 of sqlite into exe in vb.net and extract approprate for system

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I want to develop vb.net application that use sqlite database .
Sqlite database require interop.dll and I want to embed interop.dll into exe
but I could't.
I want to get exe only without any additional files.

Comment: Looks like Interop went away in 2016 : https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

Comment: Try something like the SmartAssembly by Red Gate.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to do this?  Can you give a little more detail than "but I could't"?

Comment: @Mohsen Asem I would have a look at Inno Setup this is the easiest way to include files in your setup directory I do not think you can include files into the exe file This Link will explain how to use Setup Project NOT my favorite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541888/setup-file-failing-debugging-enabled